# React eating lot's of chrome browser memory

Tags: reactjs, performance, google-chrome, react-devtools

I have an react application where there requirement is insert record in db (in the background performing some operation) the  and then display on UI. Here we are using Ag-grid on UI.
For some reason, react application eating lot's of browser memory. I did check profiler and Chrome performance tab, but to be honest I am not able to identify which part of the code eating memory?
when I checked the task manager it's showing 7899 MB only for Chrome browser and CPU is 100% utilized.

Can someone give me detail steps on below

1. How to find which part of the react code is taking lots of time which cause memory issue.
2. Where can I get the detail document/tutorial, which can explain how to read the Chromes performance tab or React dev tools, profiler
3. Do we have any other tool which can help me to find the memory leak in my react application.